# What is more efficient when programming in objective C? Structs or some objective C data type similar to structs?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

Are there any more efficient data types in objective c that implements structs, or is the C struct, even though used in objective c more efficient?

Comment: Do you have anything you are attempting to compare to? Such as a feature in another language?

Answer (score 4):

**The most efficient storage mechanism is one that gets your app to market before your competition while offering a decent user experience.**

Are you really working with so much data that you have measured a performance hit that matters?

For plain old structured, non-persisted, data, I use Objective-C classes with a series of `@property` declarations for the various fields.  Doing this allows memory management to remain encapsulated with the data and I can easily refactor this into a full-blown class with persistence and/or business logic later.

For persisted data, I use Core Data for just about everything but pure archival of object graphs.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a data only record (i.e. no methods) the C struct is the most efficient in terms of space and speed.

However, Objective-C objects are implemented as C structs under the hood, so raw member access is as fast as for a C struct.  People tend not to use that because the advantages of using accessors outweigh the speed penalty in most situations.

Comment: Nice answer. And for serializing and de serializing these custom objects, what would be the best technique? transferring these attributes and key value pairs to a plist or an actual archive?

Comment: @user773578: I'd use a plistm for small amounts of structured data that I don't need to read frequently and an archive for larger quantities of data that I do.  With Objective-C, for persistence I tend to use Core Data with an sqlite3 backing store.  Then the framework takes care of all of that.

Comment: Thanks. Where would you save the plist? as with iOS 5.0 there will be restrictions on the documents directory.

Comment: @user773578: I can't comment on iOS 5 since if I have seen the docs on it, I havwe also signed Apple's NDA.  For other versions I'd use the documents directory, unless it was config information in which case I'd use NSUserDefaults.